# How many different ways can we see this specific values on a BST lookup of a given value?

Tags: math, data-structures, binary-search-tree, traversal, combinatorics

#### [The problem statement](http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-it-2007-question-29/)

> When searching for the key value 60 in a binary search tree, nodes containing the key values 10, 20, 40, 50, 70 80, 90 are traversed, not necessarily in the order given. How many different orders are possible in which these key values can occur on the search path from the root to the node containing the value 60?

Ans : 7!/(3!4!)

I don't know how they come up with the answer.

I could come up with the following two things

```
10
  \
   20
     \
      40
        \
         50
           \
            70
              \
               80
                 \
                  90
                 /
                60
```

and

```
         90
        /
      80
     /
   70
  /
10
  \
   20
     \
      30
        \
         40
           \
            50
              \
               60
```

When I try some other thing, I couldn't following along from the root to the node which contains 60 by visiting all the given values.

e.g.

```
         50
        /  \
      40    90
     /     /
   20    80
  /     /
10    70
     /
   60
```

In the above example I can only visit 50, 90, 80, 70, 60 in the order while 10, 20 and 40 are left out. so how the answer is come up as it claims to be ?

Maybe I couldn't understand the question. maybe all the nodes needn't be visited. In that case how to come up with the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little thought experiment: is it possible that the root of the BST holds the value 20, given the information provided? If so, you would then proceed to move to the right subtree in the search for 60 (since 60 > 20), but in that case you would never see the value 10 because 10 has to be in the left subtree!

Similarly, could the root of the tree be 80? If so, in your search for 60, you'd move to the left in the first step (60 < 80), but then you'd never see 90 because 90 is in the left subtree!

This shows us that there's something interesting going on with our tree roots. Not all of these values can be the root of the BST if we see all of these values on the search for 60.

So what *could* we see as the root? One option would be to see 10. Since all the remaining values in the collection are greater than 10, that doesn't rule anything out. The other option is 90, since all the remaining values in the collection are less than 90.

We can now ask the same question about the root of the subtree that we descend into after seeing the root. We have to either see the largest of the remaining values or the smallest of the remaining values, since otherwise (using similar reasoning) we'd cut off some of the values we were supposed to see.

More generally, each value we see either needs to be (1) the greatest value greater than 60 or (2) the smallest value less than 60. Any other value won't work and will cut off some value.

Of the values provided, four of them (10, 20, 40, 50) are less than 60, and three of them (70, 80, 90) are greater than 60. As we do the search for 60, at each point we need to either pick the smallest value from the first group or the largest value from the second group as the next value that we see in the tree search. We can therefore imagine a possible search for 60 as a string of Ls and Rs, where R means "pick the smallest value from the left group" and L means "pick the largest value from the right group." For example, RRRRLLL would give us this search path:

```
                10
                  \ R
                   20
                     \ R
                      40
                        \ R
                        50
                          \ R
                           90
                          / L
                         80
                        / L
                      70
                     / L
                    60
```

The sequence RLRLRLR would give us

```
                     10
                       \ R
                       90
                       / L
                      20
                       \ R
                       80
                       / L
                      40
                       \ R
                       70
                       / L
                      50
                       \ R
                        60
```

So the answer to our overall question is now the following: how many ways can you make a string of 4 R's and 3 L's? The answer is 7 choose 4 (also equal to 7 choose 3): we have seven positions in our string, and we can either pick four of them to be R with the rest being L or pick three of them to be L with the rest being R. That works out to 7! / (4! 3!), which matches the answer you saw.